# How to deserialize JSON array of list elements in Java?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a given JSON:

```
    {
  "facility-no": "2011",
  "standard-counter": [
    {
      "id": "0",
      "type": "0",
      "text": "Gebucht",
      "free": "0",
      "present": "0",
      "percent": "100",
      "max": "0",
      "status": "Frei",
      "status-value": "0"
    }, ...
], ...
}
```

and I want it to deserialize into my classes...

A wrapper class:

```
public class Counters {

    @JsonProperty("facility-no")
    private String facilityId;

    @JsonProperty("standard-counter")
    private List<XCounter> xCounters;
}
```

The class implementing the object kept by the list in the wrapper class:

```
public class XCounter {

    protected String id;
    @JsonIgnore
    public static final CounterTypeEnum type = CounterTypeEnum.X_COUNTER;

    // standard & level counter properties
    @JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
    String text;
    @JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
    int free;
    @JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
    int present;
    @JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
    float percent;
    @JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
    int max;
    @JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
    String status;
    @JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
    @JsonProperty("status-value")
    int statusValue;
    ...(all getters and setters...)
```

Here's my CounterTypeEnum:

```
public enum CounterTypeEnum {
    X_COUNTER(0), Y_COUNTER(1), Z_COUNTER(2);
    private int type;
    private CounterTypeEnum(final int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public int getType() {
        return this.type;
    }
}
```

However, I always get an UnrecognizedPropertyException:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "type" (Class com.foo.bar.XCounter), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@42077608; line: 1, column: 61] (through reference chain: com.foo.bar.Counters["standard-counter"]->com.foo.bar.XCounter["type"])
```

if I do not use *@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)* on class level of SuBStandardCounters.

How can I avoid this exception without using *@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)*?

Comment: Why do you want `type` not to be deserialized?

Comment: Please check if getter method is there `getType()`

also it is annotated with @JsonProperty("type")

Comment: As I told you the JSON I get is fix. The type property may be just one of a few values which I have implemented as an enumeration. In my class XCounter it is a final/constant field which can't be set. Hence, I don't want it to be deserialized. I think it is a design failure to build the JSON as a list of different (XCounter, YCounter, ...) while all of them have a property "type" to specify the type of counter as well. I think it would be better to have either one Type(class) with an attribute "type" or having as many classes defined as needed without the necessity to have a type property.

Comment: The getters and setters are annotated as you suggested.

Comment: Simple answer:  Don't use Jackson.  Actually write code.  People spend more time trying to get Jackson to work than it would take to "just do it".

Comment: Could you show how `CounterTypeEnum` looks like?

Comment: Here you are...in the edited question.

Comment: If you are considering having multiple "counter" classes a design failure, then you should have a generic counter class with instance type field (non-static). Right?

Comment: Yes, but it's not my design failure. The JSON is as it is from 3rd party. I have to build my classes around that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider replacing your enum type with a actual class type leveraging [the Jackson's polymorphic deserialization](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization). In this case Jackson will create an instance of a certain type depending on the value of the type property.

Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonPolymorphic {
    public static String JSON = "{\n" +
            "  \"facility-no\": \"2011\",\n" +
            "  \"standard-counter\": [\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "      \"id\": \"0\",\n" +
            "      \"type\": \"0\",\n" +
            "      \"text\": \"Gebucht\",\n" +
            "      \"free\": \"0\",\n" +
            "      \"present\": \"0\",\n" +
            "      \"percent\": \"100\",\n" +
            "      \"max\": \"0\",\n" +
            "      \"status\": \"Frei\",\n" +
            "      \"status-value\": \"0\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "]\n" +
            "}";

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type")
    public static abstract class Counter {
        private final String id;

        public Counter(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }

    public static class Counters {
        private final String facilityId;
        private final List<Counter> counters;

        public Counters(@JsonProperty("facility-no") String facilityId,
                        @JsonProperty("standard-counter") List<Counter> counters) {
            this.facilityId = facilityId;
            this.counters = counters;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Counters{" +
                    "facilityId='" + facilityId + '\'' +
                    ", counters=" + counters +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    @JsonTypeName("0")
    public static class XCounter extends Counter {
        private final String text;
        private final int free;
        private final int present;
        private final float percent;
        private final int max;
        private final String status;
        private final int statusValue;

        public XCounter(@JsonProperty("id") String id,
                        @JsonProperty("text") String text,
                        @JsonProperty("free") int free,
                        @JsonProperty("present") int present,
                        @JsonProperty("percent") float percent,
                        @JsonProperty("max") int max,
                        @JsonProperty("status") String status,
                        @JsonProperty("status-value") int statusValue) {
            super(id);
            this.text = text;
            this.free = free;
            this.present = present;
            this.percent = percent;
            this.max = max;
            this.status = status;
            this.statusValue = statusValue;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "XCounter{" +
                    "text='" + text + '\'' +
                    ", free=" + free +
                    ", present=" + present +
                    ", percent=" + percent +
                    ", max=" + max +
                    ", status='" + status + '\'' +
                    ", statusValue=" + statusValue +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerSubtypes(XCounter.class);
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(JSON, Counters.class));
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Counters{facilityId='2011', counters=[XCounter{text='Gebucht', free=0, present=0, percent=100.0, max=0, status='Frei', statusValue=0}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is,during Deserialization the default De-serializer will try and map entire Json to your Object.
But it will have no clue as to where "type"should be mapped.

Using Custom Serializer and De-serializer is good approach if you want only some fields to be mapped .

Hope this helps!

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

If you want the field to be deserialized but not serialized you have to use `@JsonIgnore` in the getter and the attribute declaration and `@JsonProperty` in the setter when using Jackson